# Should I include "time" variable in GLMM of annual tree growth over a specified time period?

Tags: time-series, glmmtmb

I've been looking through several publications on modeling (LMM or GLMM) tree growth over a specific time period and found significantly different approaches: whilst some studies use "time" variable in their modelling (e.g. y ~ x1 + x2 + time|subjectID), others seemingly omitted it from the conditional model (e.g. y ~ x1 + x2 + 1|subjectID) and modeled y(annual tree growth) only as a response variable of categorical/continuous variables (in above x1 and x2) with nested/crossed random effects.

My question is whether these publications that did not include "time" as a variable have made modelling mistakes or are there situations when modelling tree growth over a specific time period without including "time" as a predictor is preferable/allowed, as long as there's no temporal autocorrelation in the residuals?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't only one research question that can be asked about dendrochronology, there will likely be many different models that are suitable given the research questions and context. Furthermore, it could be that the most appropriate models don't converge (or other warnings are presents) that requires the researcher to remove/adjust certain modeling terms, e.g. whether to use `+(1|SubjectID)` vs `+(time|SubjectID)` etc.

So your question,

> Should I include "time" variable in GLMM of annual tree growth over a specified time period?

cannot be answered because your don't provide any context on **your** research design and questions - instead it seems you try to judge by the work of others what model you should use. This approach will very likely not be satisfactory to answer your own question(s).

Comment: On the contrary, I've been looking at studies with the same research question, but different modelling techniques applied - i.e. in my context: what is the influence of several categorical and continuous predictors (mainly climate parameters and competition) on tree growth over a specified time period (e.g. 1980 - 2020) of a predetermined subgroup of trees (large and old trees that have all shown a trend of increasing growth since the 1980s following increase in average temperatures). Tree growth is shown as basal area increment over each tree for each year.

Comment: As I understand it: including "time" variable is then not neccessary if I'm looking at modeling the growth trend over several decades (as long as there is no temporal autocorrelation in the residuals)?